# Error digital envelope routines::unsupported while running yarn start -ssl

Tags: angular, yarn-lock.json

I am getting the below error while running `yarn start -ssl`.

I have tried `yarn install again` as ChatGPT says but still no use:

Error:

> ```
> Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
>     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
>     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
>     at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:145:18)
>     at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
>     at OriginalSource.updateHash (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/OriginalSource.js:104:8)
>     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:868:17)
>     at handleParseResult (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:934:10)
>     at /Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1026:4
>     at processResult (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:743:11)
>     at /Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5
> ⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
>   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
>                   ^
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
>     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
>     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
>     at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:145:18)
>     at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
>     at OriginalSource.updateHash (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/OriginalSource.js:104:8)
>     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:868:17)
>     at handleParseResult (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:934:10)
>     at /Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1026:4
>     at processResult (/Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:743:11)
>     at /Users/abhijith/Downloads/2205/js-storefront/teststore/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5 {
>   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
>   library: 'digital envelope routines',
>   reason: 'unsupported',
>   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }
>
> Node.js v18.16.0
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> ```

Comment: Need more details, like scripts in package.json or some source code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.